# Android ADT v14 for eclipse overriding custom filters

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

The new Android ADT for Eclipse seemed awesome and since I am dropping quite some data there I was pleased to create quite a few new filters.

The problem is that while the application is running and I try to select one of my custom filters the selection on the left is immediately changed to a "(Session Filter)"  and content is modified accordingly.

Anyone knows how to override this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*<strike>I'm not aware of any way to deactivate the automatic session filter, but it does seem buggy, even in r15. I have the opposite problem... I can't seem to get the automatic session filter to appear consistently, though after a while it finally spontaneously appears (this can be after running my project many times in a given session but it seems to stick around once it appears... at least it did in r14... it hasn't worked for me yet in r15 but I just updated).</strike>*

Actually, I think found a way after all! In **Window -> Preference -> Android -> LogCat**, if you check "Display logcat view..." it seems to be what allows LogCat to create the automatic session filter.

Problem is, that [has other bugs](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21395), and turning it off tends to screw with the autoscroll of the LogCat filter you have active.

Anyway, change that setting and see if it helps!

Edit: Something else to consider is using **Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Logcat (deprecated)** (but who knows how long that'll be around?) Found that info [in this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20805) (which is where reports like the one I linked to earlier were consolidated to). (That's probably not very useful to you since you like the new auto filter, but it might be useful to others reading this.)